# Is is possible to create an animatable morph between two lines?

Tags: modeling, animation

I'm trying to create a morph/blend as seen in the second image, but instead of beeing the same line from start to end I want them to be like the first image different lines A and B. The result has to be animatable so I can move a vertex of the line A or B and Blender updates the inbetween-lines during animation.

Is this possible?

[image: Blend between lines]

Comment: Shapekeys sound like a useful tool here, but as far as I know there is no native way to achieve what you want without some script of some form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Animation Nodes Addon.

Create the a shapekey, morphing from A (Basis) to B (Key 1).

The (in animation nodes) instance them with the Object instancer and vary the shapekey value in a loop. Remember to check **Deep Copy**, otherwise all mesh are going to have the same shapekey value.

[image]